# Phonegap Icenium image displaying wrong way round

Tags: cordova, camera

I've taken a photo with the camer but when I set the image data to be the src of an image element it appears on its side. I upload it to a server and it displays correctly. I suspect it is something stupid I am doing.

Comment: Maybe the viewer you use to display an uploaded image is smart enough to read and apply the EXIF orientational info

Comment: The viewer I'm using is the windows 8 photo viewer. If I view it on the phone an S3 it is the right way around. But in the phone gap and also the thumbnails in the file system they are the wrong way.

Comment: It's quite possible that phonegap viewer ignores EXIF. I am not sure what is wrong with thumbnails, though.

Comment: There is an orientation setting  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onPhotoDataFail, { quality: 50, correctOrientation: true, targetWidth: 750, targetHeight: 750 }); 

Be careful to set the width because it crashed my phone trying to orientate the raw image in memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an orientation setting navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onPhotoDataFail, { quality: 50, correctOrientation: true, targetWidth: 750, targetHeight: 750 }); Be careful to set the width because it crashed my phone trying to orientate the raw image in memory

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're walking into a commonly known problem with uploading photos created with an iOS device, like an iPhone, to a Windows system.

The reason is that the photo orientation EXIF data is **interpreted differently** between Apple systems and Windows.

This known issue has been discussed in [several threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222053/problem-reading-jpeg-metadata-orientation).

Like user1102550 suggests, setting the `correctOrientation: true` property in the `getPicture()` method should work. This is also further discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353629/images-turning-sideways-upside-down-after-being-uploaded-via-phonegap-ios).